# ¿Cómo hago para asegurarme de que Excel siempre muestre los ceros?

Tags: excel, microsoft-office, informatica-power-center

Tengo un archivo CSV con la siguiente estructura:

ID      SUBCUENTA UNDCAP
3308799 05        000005

Cuando lo abro en Excel aparece la columna UNDCAP y SUBACCOUNT sin ceros, ¿Cómo hago para asegurarme de que Excel siempre muestre los ceros?

El archivo lo estoy generando desde Informatica Power Center.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Los ceros a la izquierda son eliminados automaticamente porque no valen nada (matemáticamente hablando). Una manera de mantenerlos sería tratar esa columna como campos de texto en vez de números

Comment: El problema es que esa columna no se puede tratar como texto, porque una vez se abre el archivo ya el dato esta ahí, sin los ceros.

Comment: Entonces debes de configurar el campo como texto en el excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo abres normal y corriente, con doble click sobre el propio archivo, entonces el comportamiento normal de Excel es eliminar los ceros a la izquierda, porque es una hoja de cálculo, y en matemáticas los ceros a la izquierda no tienen valor.

Tienes que importar tus datos como texto. Dependiendo de tu versión de Excel, puede cambiar un poco el proceso, pero básicamente tienes que importarlos y decirles que los importe como texto. En mi caso, he creado un archivo CSV que he llamado PRUEBA, con los datos de tu enunciado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego he hecho los siguientes pasos:

1. Abro Excel normal, un archivo nuevo en blanco
2. Pestaña datos,grupo obtener y transformar datos, desde texto/csv
3. Pedirá la ruta del archivo CSV. Lo busco y aceptar
4. Te saldrá una nueva ventana y aquí click en **transformar datos**
5. En el editor, cambia las palabras *Int64* por *Text*
6. Clic a la izquierda arriba en **Cargar y cerrar**

Los pasos en vídeo: (SO tiene un límite de solo 2 megas, así que he tenido que subir el GIF a otro sitio):

https://gifyu.com/image/YWq3

Verás que el resultado final es un archivo con los datos exportados como texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo eliminar la consulta después de la importación, para que no se vinculen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado debería ser algo así:

Comment: +1 tu respuesta es muy completa

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @BetaM, voy a mostrarla al usuario a ver que dice, esto porque ellos quieren que la info aparezca de una en el Excel, y no tener que hacer ningún paso..., muy agradecido!

Comment: @CarlosFabregas yo solo comenté para indicar mi apoyo a esta publicación, el autor y quien merece el crédito es Esei

Comment: Ahh ok, mil gracias @Esei

Answer (score 2):

Si al abrir el archivo exportado desde el software desaparecen los ceros, se pueden recuperar sin problema. Una vez abres el archivo vas al menu "Datos" y seleccionas "Fuentes Recientes". Conectas el origen, es decir el libro de excel correspondiente y luego seleccionas en "Detección de tipo de datos" la opción "No detectar tipos de datos" y les das Click en "Cargar".
Ello te carga los datos tal y como fueron exportados con el software. Ahora bien, para manipular estos datos sin que vuelvan a perder los ceros debes aplicar algunas transformaciones sencillas.
Una solución sencilla es añadir delante de los números un apostrofe (').
Por ejemplo:
'05 000005
Y excel mostraría sólo el número, no mostraría el apostrofe. Esto puedes hacerlo para todos los valores mediante la función "Concatenar"
O debes operar los datos en un rango de celdas al que hayas previamente definido formato de texto para que no borre los ceros, pues esto lo hace si el formato es "número" [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto serviría si el archivo se generase en Excel, pero el usuario ya dijo que lo genera con otra aplicación y necesita leerlo en Excel, con lo cual, no soluciona el problema.

Comment: Perdone no había posteado la respuesta completa. La he editado, ya esta

Comment: Esto sí serviría :)

Comment: Excelente, voy a comentar la respuesta al usuario a ver que le parece!, muy agradecido!!!